# Define site root to auto load php assets

Tags: php

I am trying to define the site root to easily auto load my php classes. I am fairly new and have getting a lot of grief because I physically have to change either the includes or require_once paths because a respective page is within a different folder.

I found a tutorial and applied what I have learned, however it is not working properly.

Here is what I used:

```
     defined ('DS') ? null : define ('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null :
    define('SITE_ROOT', DS. 'C:'. DS. 'xampp' .DS. 'htdocs' .DS. 'database');

defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT. DS .'includes');

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once (LIB_PATH.DS . $class . '.php');
});

require_once (LIB_PATH.DS .'functions.php');
```

Any suggestions on how to properly define the root to limit the amount of times you have to change the file paths?

Answer (score 0):

The way I have defined my doc_root that seems to work well for me is using the full absolute path in my variable.

I create a `config.inc.php` file in a folder called `includes/config` that has some contents like this.

```
    define("DOC_ROOT","/home/sitename/public_html");
    define("MODULES", DOC_ROOT."/modules");
```

You can put the file anywhere. Due to the way my site is coded I just include the config file in my `index.php` since pages are called via that file.

```
include_once("includes/config/config.inc.php");
```

However you can include that at the top of your scripts or in a header file etc.

Then when I need to use a file I can just use `require_once(DOC_ROOT."/somefolder/file.php");`

or something like

```
require_once(MODULES."/file.php");
require_once(MODULES."/someotherfile.php");
```

All works no matter the directory it's in. And shouldn't really have to change paths.